# Should I mark my smart contracts as abstract?

Tags: solidity, remix

I wrote a StandardToken contract inheriting interface Token and a BlockchainDevToken inheriting the StandardToken ; on both, the compiler on remix said:

> from solidity: TypeError: Contract "StandardToken" should be marked as abstract.
> TypeError: Contract "BlockchainDevToken" should be marked as abstract.

Here is my code:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: GPL-3.0

pragma solidity >=0.7.0 <0.9.0;
// import "Token.sol";
interface Token {
    function  totalSupply() external view returns (uint256 supply);

    function balanceOf(address _owner) external view returns (uint256 balance);

    function allowance(address _owner, address _spender) external view returns (uint256 remaining);

    function transfer(address _to, uint _value) external returns (bool didOperationSucceed);

    function approve(address _spender, uint _value) external returns (bool didOperationSucceed);

    function transferFrom(address _from, address _to, address _value) external returns (bool didOperationSucceed);

    event Transfer(address indexed from, address indexed to, uint value);

    event Approval(
        address indexed owner,
        address indexed spender,
        uint256 value
    );

}

contract StandardToken is Token {
    mapping(address => uint256) internal _balances;
    mapping(address => mapping(address => uint256)) internal _allowed;
    uint256 internal _totalSupply;

    function totalSupply() external view override returns (uint256 supply) {
        return _totalSupply;
    }

    function balanceOf(address _owner) public view override returns (uint256) {
        return _balances[_owner];
    }    

    function allowance(address _owner, address _spender) public view override returns (uint256) {
        return _allowed[_owner][_spender];
    }

    function transfer(address _to, uint _value) public override returns (bool) {
        require(_value <= _balances[msg.sender]);
        require(_to != address(0));
        require(_balances[_to] + _value > 0);    
        
        _balances[msg.sender] -= _value;
        _balances[_to] += _value;
        emit Transfer(msg.sender, _to, _value);
        return true;
    }

    function approve(address _spender, uint256 _value) public override returns (bool){
        require(_spender != address(0));

        _allowed[msg.sender][_spender] = _value;
        emit Approval(msg.sender, _spender, _value);
        return true;
    }

    function transferFrom(address _from, address _to, uint256 _value) public returns (bool){
        require(_value <= _balances[_from]);
        require(_value <= _allowed[_from][msg.sender]);
        require(_to != address(0));
        require(_balances[_to] + _value > 0);

        _balances[_from] -= _value;
        _allowed[_from][msg.sender] -= _value;
        _balances[_to] += _value;
        emit Transfer(_from, _to, _value);
        return true;
    }

}   


contract BlockchainDevToken is StandardToken {
    string public name;
    uint8 public decimals;
    string public symbol;
    uint256 public unitsOneEthCanBuy;
    uint256 public totalRaisedEthInWei;
    address payable public owner;

    constructor() {
        decimals = 18;
        _totalSupply = 1000000000000000000000;
        _balances[msg.sender] = _totalSupply;
        
        name = "Blockchain Dev Token";
        symbol = "BDT";
        unitsOneEthCanBuy = 10;

        owner = payable(msg.sender);
    }

    receive() external payable {
        totalRaisedEthInWei += msg.value;
        uint256 amount = msg.value * unitsOneEthCanBuy;
        require(_balances[owner] >= amount);
        _balances[owner] -= amount;
        _balances[msg.sender] += amount;
        emit Transfer(owner, msg.sender, amount);
        owner.transfer(msg.value);
    }
    
}
```

Can anyone clarify how I should go about this? And why its saying they "need to be abstract?"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just have one small mistake :

Your interface defines the following function :

```
function transferFrom(address _from, address _to, address _value) external returns (bool didOperationSucceed);
```

Where the parameter `_value` is of type `address`, it should probably be `uint256`.

Additionally, in `StandardToken` you are missing the override modifier for `transferFrom`, it should look like this :

```
function transferFrom(address _from, address _to, uint256 _value) public override returns (bool)
```

You should be able to compile with those 2 small modifications.

I hope it answers your question.